# Hiding div with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using the following code to hide the text based on the answer given. Its so simple but i must be missing something. What am I doing wrong?

```
$('.nameclass').on('change', function() {
        if( $('input[name=idname]').val() == '1' ) {
        $('#idname').removeClass('hide');
        } else {
            $('#idname').addClass('hide');
        }
    });


        <div class="hide" id="idname"> 
             <legend>To be hidden depending on answer</legend>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What element has the class to match `$('.tenaamstellingclass')`? Have you checked your console for errors?

Comment: Besides the element with the class `tenaamstellingclass` is not present in your excerpt - does the class `hide` actually hide the element? You can also try `$('#tenaamstelling_volmacht').show()` / `$('#tenaamstelling_volmacht').hide()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `select` selector is not correct. In the listener selector, there is no `tenaamstellingclass` assigned class to the select box. In the if statement you are trying to get the select box by using `input[name=tenaamstelling]` when you should use it like `select[name=tenaamstelling]` because it is a select box and not an input field.

You can either add the `tenaamstellingclass` class to your `select` input, or use this code.

Just replace this:

```
$('.tenaamstellingclass').on('change', function() {
    if( $('input[name=tenaamstelling]').val() == 'VOLMACHT' ) {
    $('#tenaamstelling_volmacht').removeClass('hide');
    } else {
        $('#tenaamstelling_volmacht').addClass('hide');
    }
});
```

with:

```
$('select[name="tenaamstelling"]').on('change', function() {
    if( $(this).val() == 'VOLMACHT' ) {
        $('#tenaamstelling_volmacht').removeClass('hide');
    } else {
        $('#tenaamstelling_volmacht').addClass('hide');
    }
});
```

Now, if the `.hide` is defined correctly in your CSS, everything should be fine

You can check it here:

https://jsfiddle.net/vk3o6gyc/

Given your HTML, the default for the `#tenaamstelling_volmacht` div is hidden and when option 2 is selected it is then displayed.